# Where should i look for Yii2 log exception file

Tags: php, yii2

A beginner to Yii 2 framework, can anyone please tell me where do i find the log exception file or if have to create the file to store all exceptions then how should i create one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're are using the *Advanced Application Template*, each app (frontend, backend) has his own `runtime/logs` folder with a log file.

Also, you can add in config file this setting, for components, to receive and email every time a level of error you've set, occurs:

```
'log' => [
            'targets' => [
                'email' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error'],
                    'message' => [
                        'from' => 'app-email', 
                        'to' => 'your-email',
                        'subject' => 'Log message',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Very useful for production.

Comment: To clarify, for me it was YOUR_CODE/api/runtime/logs

Answer (score 5):

By default, Yii2 logs error and warning level events into the `runtime/logs/app.log` file. You can read more about configuring logging in Yii2 in e.g. the [Definitive Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html).